# Does changing the window location in Javascript kill the current/upcoming events on the event loop?

Tags: javascript

So in this scenario this happen.

1. An async Ajax request is made. It is of course scheduled into an event.
2. `window.location.href` is set to some other page, causing a new page to load.

What happens to the ajax call? Does it perform a full and complete GET/POST/etc request? Or is it never called, or canceled? In general, how does Javacsript handle the eventloop when a new page loads?

Comment: Yes it does stop execution. Not sure *when and how though*, I'll dig into the web spec.

Answer (score 3):

> In general, how does Javascript handle the eventloop when a new page loads?

JS itself provides no ways to stop a running script, thats implementation specific. Browsers however have their own spec, and that [basically says](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#unloading-document-cleanup-steps) that unloading an object kills all event sources (timers, websockets, etc.). Therefore, the engine just runs empty.

> What happens to the ajax call?

It will get aborted.

> Does it perform a full and complete GET/POST/etc request? Or is it never called, or canceled?

Yes, exactly that, it'll cancel the request. That can happen at various points of the fetch process (search for "terminate" in the related [spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-fetch)).